# Is it possible to use PostgreSQL driver in r programs on local dataframes via sqldf?

Tags: r, postgresql, sqldf

Of course, it is possible to connect from r to a PostgreSQL server and use sqldf to run queries on that server. But is it possible to use PostgreSQL's SQL syntax and functions on local dataframes without even establishing a connection to a remote server? I know that by choosing SQLite driver this is possible but I'm more interested in PostgreSQL syntax and possibilities.

Thanks in advance